# Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /XXX/post.php on line XXXX

Tags: php, wordpress, strpos

I have such a prolem since I had to change the server provider.
I was porting a few wordpress based sites using the Duplicator plugin. Now wherever in the content of the page I use the  tag, it returns an error

> Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /XXX/post.php on line XXXX

It's about the code:

```
function is_local_attachment($url) {

  if (strpos($url, home_url()) === false) {
    return false;
  }

  if (strpos($url, home_url('/? attachment_id =')) ! == false) {
    return true;
  }

  $id = url_to_postid($url);

  if ($id) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ('attachment' == $post-> post_type) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

and more specifically about the line:

```
if (strpos($url, home_url()) === false) {
```

Has anyone had such a case and knows how to solve it?

Everything was fine before the server switch. And I wish it would continue to be the case. I'd rather not fix the bug, but find and eliminate what led to it.

The only thing that comes to mind is whether I didn't have Site Address URL on the previous server, I don't have to have it on the new one - the field is empty.

Comment: Please read error message. Closing due to typo.

Comment: `the field is empty`...yes, that's what the warning message is telling you! Better to fill in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to put a "guard clause" in. Something like this:

```
function is_local_attachment($url) {

  $homeUrl = home_url();

  if (empty($home_url)) {
    return;
  }
  . . .
```

I don't know what `home_url()` returns but obviously it can return an empty string and that is causing you a probelm.

If you are using PHP 7.1 or higher you could use something like:

```
if (strpos($url, home_url()??' ') === false)
```

Personally, I wouldn't because it's more difficult to read, but it would solve your problem.

Cheers! :)

=C=